# When refreshing a submitted content on Google Chrome, confirmation prompt doesn't get focused

Tags: google-chrome, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

Here is the scenario: whenever I submit a form on Google Chrome, then try to refresh the page, I get prompted by the browser to confirm the re-submition, due to data loss et cetera, as usual. The annoying part is that the confirmation prompt doesn't get the focus (it used to do it).

This is a common task I believe many programmers do:

1. CTRL+S on code editor;
2. ALT+TAB to Google Chrome and
3. CTRL+R (or F5) to refresh the page.
4. **RETURN or SPACE to confirm the re-submition.**

The problem is at the 4th step: once the confirmation prompt doesn't get the focus, I have to mouse click the "OK" button.

It's not a big deal, but it really becomes a pain when you have to test multiple times a form submition.

My Chrome version is: 27.0.1453.94 m

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same experience. My Chrome version is 27.0.1453.110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I noticed the same behavior in Chrome 27.0.1453.94 m, it's very annoying when developing webpages. The problem persists in version 27.0.1453.110 m.</strike>

I've tried 29.0.1529.3 **canary**, it's refresh behavior is back to normal in that version.

Today i noticed that this behaviour is fixed :-)
Current version: 28.0.1500.71 m